# Determine if a Database is "Equal" to a DacPackage

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

Is there a way to use [the SQL Server 2012 Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dac(v=sql.110).aspx) to determine if a database has an identical schema to that described by a [DacPackage object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dac.dacpackage(v=sql.110).aspx)? I've looked at the API docs for DacPackage as well as [DacServices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dac.dacservices(v=sql.110).aspx), but not having any luck; am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I've come up with, but I'm not really crazy about it. If anyone can point out any bugs, edge cases, or better approaches, I'd be much obliged.

```
...
DacServices dacSvc = new DacServices(connectionString);
string deployScript = dacSvc.GenerateDeployScript(myDacpac, @"aDb", deployOptions);

if (DatabaseEqualsDacPackage(deployScript))
{
  Console.WriteLine("The database and the DacPackage are equal");
}
...
bool DatabaseEqualsDacPackage(string deployScript)
{
  string equalStr = string.Format("GO{0}USE [$(DatabaseName)];{0}{0}{0}GO{0}PRINT N'Update complete.'{0}GO", Environment.NewLine);
  return deployScript.Contains(equalStr);
}
...
```

What I really don't like about this approach is that it's entirely dependent upon the format of the generated deployment script, and therefore extremely brittle. Questions, comments and suggestions very welcome.

Comment: I have posted a solution that has worked well for me over the years.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is, I have been using the following technique since 2012 without issue.

1. Calculate a fingerprint of the dacpac.
2. Store that fingerprint in the target database.

> The .dacpac is just a zip file containing goodies like metadata, and
>   model information.

Here's a screen-grab of what you will find in the .dacpac:

[image: screenshot of dacpac and its content]

The file **model.xml** has XML structured like the following

```
<DataSchemaModel>
    <Header>
        ... developer specific stuff is in here
    </Header>
    <Model>
        .. database model definition is in here
    </Model>
</<DataSchemaModel>
```

> What we need to do is extract the contents from `<Model>...</Model>`
>   and treat this as the *fingerprint* of the schema.

**"But wait!"** you say.  **"Origin.xml** has the following nodes:"

```
<Checksums>
    <Checksum Uri="/model.xml">EB1B87793DB57B3BB5D4D9826D5566B42FA956EDF711BB96F713D06BA3D309DE</Checksum>
</Checksums>
```

In my experience, this `<Checksum>` node changes regardless of a schema change in the model.

So let's get to it.
**Calculate the *fingerprint* of the dacpac.**

```
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Packaging;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
static string DacPacFingerprint(byte[] dacPacBytes)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(dacPacBytes))
    using (var package = ZipPackage.Open(ms))
    {
        var modelFile = package.GetPart(new Uri("/model.xml", UriKind.Relative));
        using (var streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(modelFile.GetStream()))
        {
            var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument() { InnerXml = streamReader.ReadToEnd() };
            foreach (XmlNode childNode in xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
            {
                if (childNode.Name == "Header")
                {
                    // skip the Header node as described
                    xmlDoc.DocumentElement.RemoveChild(childNode);
                    break;
                }
            }
            using (var crypto = new SHA512CryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                byte[] retVal = crypto.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlDoc.InnerXml));
                return BitConverter.ToString(retVal).Replace("-", "");// hex string
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this fingerprint now available, pseudo code for applying a dacpac can be:

```
void main()
{
    var dacpacBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("<path-to-dacpac>");
    var dacpacFingerPrint = DacPacFingerprint(dacpacBytes);// see above
    var databaseFingerPrint = Database.GetFingerprint();//however you choose to do this
    if(databaseFingerPrint != dacpacFingerPrint)
    {
        DeployDacpac(...);//however you choose to do this
        Database.SetFingerprint(dacpacFingerPrint);//however you choose to do this
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Aaron! I've switched jobs so I'm not really able to try out your change, but I've shared it with a former co-worker because it looks solid.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I modified it to also include post deploy script

Answer (score 1):

@Aaron Hudon answer does not account for post script changes. Sometimes you just add a new entry to a type table without changing the model. In our case we want this to count as new dacpac. Here is my modification of his code to account for that

```
private static string DacPacFingerprint(string path)
{
    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
    using (var package = Package.Open(stream))
    {
        var extractors = new IDacPacDataExtractor [] {new ModelExtractor(), new PostScriptExtractor()};
        string content = string.Join("_", extractors.Select(e =>
        {
            var modelFile = package.GetPart(new Uri($"/{e.Filename}", UriKind.Relative));
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(modelFile.GetStream()))
            {
                return e.ExtractData(streamReader);
            }
        }));

        using (var crypto = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            byte[] retVal = crypto.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content));
            return BitConverter.ToString(retVal).Replace("-", "");// hex string
        }
    }
}


private class ModelExtractor : IDacPacDataExtractor
{
    public string Filename { get; } = "model.xml";
    public string ExtractData(StreamReader streamReader)
    {
        var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument() { InnerXml = streamReader.ReadToEnd() };
        foreach (XmlNode childNode in xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (childNode.Name == "Header")
            {
                // skip the Header node as described
                xmlDoc.DocumentElement.RemoveChild(childNode);
                break;
            }
        }

        return xmlDoc.InnerXml;
    }
}

private class PostScriptExtractor : IDacPacDataExtractor
{
    public string Filename { get; } = "postdeploy.sql";
    public string ExtractData(StreamReader stream)
    {
        return stream.ReadToEnd();
    }
}

private interface IDacPacDataExtractor
{
    string Filename { get; }
    string ExtractData(StreamReader stream);
}
```